# Sqrt method returns 0

Tags: powershell, sqrt

I need a method which returns the standard deviation of the last access time in a folder. Here is the code:

```
function standardDeviation {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$tPath
    )

    $moy = moyAge $tPath
    $variance = 0
    $nbFiles = 1
    dir | ForEach-Object {
        if (!($_.PsIsContainer)) {
            $nbDays = $_.LastAccessTime
            $nbDays = $nbDays.Days
            $sq = $nbDays - $moy
            $sq = $sq*$sq
            $variance += $sq
            $nbFiles++
        }
    }
    $variance = $variance / $nbFiles
    $variance = [math]::sqrt($variance)
}
```

I don't know why, but it always returns 0. Does someone know why?
(`moyAge` works, and returns an int (number of days))

Comment: The function looks odd. `moyAge` isn't defined and `dir` is not bases on `$tPath`.

Comment: The parameter was here for a reason, but not anymore. moyAge is a function which returns an int, and it works.

Comment: `[datetime]` doesn't have a `Days` property, `$nbDays` is `$null`

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't actually return anything, so any call will "return" `$null`. Either change

```
$variance = [math]::sqrt($variance)
```

to

```
[math]::sqrt($variance)
```

or add a line

```
$variance
```

or

```
return $variance
```

at the end of the function.

Also, as @MathiasRJessen pointed out, `DateTime` objects don't have a `Days` property. If you want the difference in days between today and a specific date you need to calculate a timespan first:

```
$nbDays = ((Get-Date).Date - $_.LastAccessTime.Date).Days
```